# Strange results with box-whisker plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am drawing a box-whisker diagram. The code is below. There are six vertical box items. Apart from the numbers, each box is coded identically (actually generated by a program). So I cannot understand the following results:

Box 2 and 6 have the actual box outlined in red rather than black.
Box 6 also has the median and whisker lines dashed rather than solid.

What is causing this?  How can identical code produce different results?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6cm,height=5cm,
   xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   yticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},xtick pos=left,
   xtick align=outside,ytick pos=bottom,ytick align=outside,
   xlabel={Till number},xlabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   ylabel={Walk-time},ylabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   legend style={font=\scriptsize,at={(rel axis cs:0.50,0.02)},anchor=south},
   xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
   boxplot/draw direction=y,
   boxplot/every box/.style={fill=gray!70},
   boxplot/every whisker/.style={black,very thick},
   boxplot/every median/.style={black,very thick},
  ];
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=1.32,
 lower quartile=2.04,median=2.44,
 upper quartile=2.8,upper whisker=5.04}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=2.28,
 lower quartile=3.08,median=3.72,
 upper quartile=4.24,upper whisker=5.72}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=3.72,
 lower quartile=4.68,median=5.081,
 upper quartile=5.8,upper whisker=7.04}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=5.08,
 lower quartile=5.8,median=6.451,
 upper quartile=7.28,upper whisker=9.428}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=6.146,
 lower quartile=7.082,median=7.813,
 upper quartile=8.648,upper whisker=10.776}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=6.146,
 lower quartile=7.082,median=7.813,
 upper quartile=8.648,upper whisker=10.776}
     ] coordinates{};     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Apoligies for the unformatted PgfPlots code - it was formatted when I pasted it in, but the line breaks seem to get lost on pasting.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that come into play. First, `pgfplots` have the notion of `cycle list`s, which are essentially lists of styles that are used for consecutive plots, unless the style is defined explicitly. For example, the code below, which just makes six straight lines at different y-values, produces this:

[image: output of first code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[no markers,samples=2,height=3cm,width=4cm]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,6}{
  \addplot {#1};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the first line is blue, the second red etc. The sixth line is dashed.

The second thing is that you use `\addplot +[..]` instead of `\addplot [..]`. The `+` indicates that the style in the brackets are *appended* to the style defined by the active cycle list. So the line style defined by your style settings for the boxplot come in addition to those defined by the cycle list.

There are two ways of solving this. Either, remove all the `+` signs, which means that `pgfplots` will not use the cycle list, and instead revert to TikZ's, which is a solid black line, plus any style you define.

Or you can modify your style settings to specify that lines should be black and not dashed, i.e. `draw=black, solid`:

```
boxplot/every box/.style={fill=gray!70,draw=black,solid},
boxplot/every whisker/.style={black,very thick,solid},
boxplot/every median/.style={black,very thick,solid},
```

Both options will produce this:

[image: all black boxplots]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % it's recommended to have a compat-setting
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6cm,height=5cm,
   xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   yticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},xtick pos=left,
   xtick align=outside,ytick pos=bottom,ytick align=outside,
   xlabel={Till number},xlabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   ylabel={Walk-time},ylabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   legend style={font=\scriptsize,at={(rel axis cs:0.50,0.02)},anchor=south},
   xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
   boxplot/draw direction=y,
   boxplot/every box/.style={fill=gray!70,draw=black,solid},
   boxplot/every whisker/.style={black,very thick,solid},
   boxplot/every median/.style={black,very thick,solid},
  ];
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=1.32,
 lower quartile=2.04,median=2.44,
 upper quartile=2.8,upper whisker=5.04}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=2.28,
 lower quartile=3.08,median=3.72,
 upper quartile=4.24,upper whisker=5.72}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=3.72,
 lower quartile=4.68,median=5.081,
 upper quartile=5.8,upper whisker=7.04}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=5.08,
 lower quartile=5.8,median=6.451,
 upper quartile=7.28,upper whisker=9.428}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=6.146,
 lower quartile=7.082,median=7.813,
 upper quartile=8.648,upper whisker=10.776}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=6.146,
 lower quartile=7.082,median=7.813,
 upper quartile=8.648,upper whisker=10.776}
     ] coordinates{};     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6cm,height=5cm,
   xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   yticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},xtick pos=left,
   xtick align=outside,ytick pos=bottom,ytick align=outside,
   xlabel={Till number},xlabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   ylabel={Walk-time},ylabel style={font=\scriptsize},
   legend style={font=\scriptsize,at={(rel axis cs:0.50,0.02)},anchor=south},
   xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
   boxplot/draw direction=y,
   boxplot/every box/.style={fill=gray!70},
   boxplot/every whisker/.style={black,very thick},
   boxplot/every median/.style={black,very thick},
  ];
\addplot[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=1.32,
 lower quartile=2.04,median=2.44,
 upper quartile=2.8,upper whisker=5.04}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=2.28,
 lower quartile=3.08,median=3.72,
 upper quartile=4.24,upper whisker=5.72}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=3.72,
 lower quartile=4.68,median=5.081,
 upper quartile=5.8,upper whisker=7.04}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=5.08,
 lower quartile=5.8,median=6.451,
 upper quartile=7.28,upper whisker=9.428}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=6.146,
 lower quartile=7.082,median=7.813,
 upper quartile=8.648,upper whisker=10.776}
     ] coordinates{};
\addplot[boxplot prepared={lower whisker=6.146,
 lower quartile=7.082,median=7.813,
 upper quartile=8.648,upper whisker=10.776}
     ] coordinates{};     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will just remove the + signs. I just copied the code from an example (on here I think) just to get something working, without understanding the details.